# Arduino Loop not recognizing break condition?

Tags: arduino

I currently have a nested for loop system that is writing commands to a motor and reading from the attached encoder. For some reason, the program will not break out of the loop using the conditional. I have used some print statements to debug a little and it clearly recognizes that PWMcount is greater than 76 as it prints as far as I will let it count. Any advice is much appreciated, Thank You!

```
for(int PWMcount = 58;PWMcount < 76;) { //10-20 RAMP
        for (int counter = 1; counter < 4;) {
          if (counter != 3) {
              finalTime = millis();                                                           
              float newPos;          
              newPos = encoder.read();   
              if (newPos != oldPos) {                                                    
                deltaTime = (finalTime - initialTime);                            
                deltaPos = (newPos-oldPos);                                       
                oldPos = newPos;                                                    
                initialTime = finalTime;                              
                //Serial.println(deltaPos/deltaTime);                    
              }
              counter = counter+1;
              delay(100);
             // Serial.println(PWMcount);
          }
          else {
              
              finalTime = millis();                                                    //catches time for beginning of each loop iteration           
              float newPos;          
              newPos = encoder.read();   
              if (newPos != oldPos) {                                                    //Checks for encoder movement
                deltaTime = (finalTime - initialTime);                            //calculates deltaT in milliseconds
                deltaPos = (newPos-oldPos);                                       //sets change in position from one iteration to the next
                oldPos = newPos;                                                       //Sets old to new to fail if statement unless movement is detected.
                initialTime = finalTime;                                 //sets time at beginning of loop to time of ending last loop in order to correctly calculate deltaT in the next iteration
                //Serial.println(deltaPos/deltaTime);                      //Prints rate of the encoder disk in deg/ms (Confirmed by manually taking data and seeing that 1 Rotation outputs values from 0-360
                  
              }
              counter = 1;
              PWMcount=PWMcount+1;   
              analogWrite(RPWM_Output, PWMcount); // Increases Motor PWM in accordance to loop
          }
          Serial.println(PWMcount);       // UNCOMMENT TO TROUBLESHOOT PWM
          delay(100);
        }
      }
```

Comment: On what line do you want to break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `for` loop never completes:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter < 4;)
```

The body of the loop is a single `if` statement. On the last iteration of the loop, the `else` branch is taken, and that branch sets the loop variable `counter` back to `1`, so the expression `counter < 4` is always true, and so that loop never exits.

Since it never exits, the code never gets to a point where the outer loop conditional is tested, nor where the outer loop would ever branch back to the beginning at all.

One possible way to fix the situation would be to combine the two loop conditions, making it a single loop:

```
for(int PWMcount = 58, counter = 1; PWMcount < 76;) { //10-20 RAMP
  if (counter != 3) {
      finalTime = millis();                                                           
      float newPos;          
      newPos = encoder.read();   
      if (newPos != oldPos) {                                                    
        deltaTime = (finalTime - initialTime);                            
        deltaPos = (newPos-oldPos);                                       
        oldPos = newPos;                                                    
        initialTime = finalTime;                              
        //Serial.println(deltaPos/deltaTime);                    
      }
      counter = counter+1;
      delay(100);
     // Serial.println(PWMcount);
  }
  else {
      
      finalTime = millis();                                                    //catches time for beginning of each loop iteration           
      float newPos;          
      newPos = encoder.read();   
      if (newPos != oldPos) {                                                    //Checks for encoder movement
        deltaTime = (finalTime - initialTime);                            //calculates deltaT in milliseconds
        deltaPos = (newPos-oldPos);                                       //sets change in position from one iteration to the next
        oldPos = newPos;                                                       //Sets old to new to fail if statement unless movement is detected.
        initialTime = finalTime;                                 //sets time at beginning of loop to time of ending last loop in order to correctly calculate deltaT in the next iteration
        //Serial.println(deltaPos/deltaTime);                      //Prints rate of the encoder disk in deg/ms (Confirmed by manually taking data and seeing that 1 Rotation outputs values from 0-360
          
      }
      counter = 1;
      PWMcount=PWMcount+1;   
      analogWrite(RPWM_Output, PWMcount); // Increases Motor PWM in accordance to loop

      Serial.println(PWMcount);       // UNCOMMENT TO TROUBLESHOOT PWM
      delay(100);
  }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- The loop condition does not bother to check the `counter` value, because the loop body obviates the comparison. The `counter` variable is always less than `4`.
- I moved the last two lines of the outer loop into the `else` branch of the `if` statement. They never executed in your original code, so maybe you just want to remove them altogether. But if the intent was to execute those two lines each line the inner loop reached its end (i.e. `counter` is `3`), then this change matches that intent.